# socket.io not falling back to other methods when blocked behind firewall

Tags: socket.io

I've got my client side socket config settings as

```
    io.set('transports', [
        'websocket',
        'flashsocket',
        'htmlfile',
        'xhr-polling',
        'jsonp-polling'
    ]);
```

When I am behind my corporate firewall, The client claims to connect to the server. But then when I try and send/receive message, it doesn't work. I need it to just fallback to another transport method, but, can't figure out how to configure it to do that.

How can I detect if I am behind a corporate firewall (and therefore not "truly" connected to socket even when I receive a connected response) and then fallback on another method?

Note that this prints "connected" out to the console behind the firewall, but then when I try and send/receive messages, it doesn't work:

```
        app.iosocket.on('connect', function(){
            console.log('connected');
        });
```

Comment: There could be another reason for your problem. It would be much easier if you post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach event listeners to the 'connection', 'connect' and 'error' events to inspect what going wrong.